# Tree Filter Ext Js

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a anyway we can filter a tree node using attribute(except 'text') in ExtJs. I have tried with text filtering its working .

where re=user typed text

```
var val = field.getRawValue();
var re = new RegExp('.*' + val + '.*', 'i');
this.ActiveTree.filter.clear(); 
this.ActiveTree.filter.filter(re,'text');
```

I want to get the filter in attribute level. for example a tree which has attribute of ('CC') in the child node then i want to display all its parent.

assume CC-color code. value : #3ADF00 this value present in all child node of tree during tree construction based on some condition. Now i want to filter only those node and parents to construct a new tree from existing one.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what extjs version is that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried

```
var val = '#3ADF00';var re = new RegExp('.*' + val + '.*', 'i');this.ActiveTree.filter.clear(); this.ActiveTree.filter.filter(re,'CC');
```

This is working fine the way i expected.